# testing for continuous uniform distribution in python

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, large-data, anderson-darling-test

I'm setting up a statistical experiment. I am investigating whether a list of real values follows a continuous uniform distribution. In scipy, there is kstest to do it, I find it not robust after several tests on synthetic data. I have another test but without result. This test is as follows: given my list of real values L of size n, I synthetically generate uniformly distributed data T of size n as well. With the function anderson_ksamp I look if L and T are of the same distribution. If this is the case then L is forcibly uniform. I find that this test only works for small sets of tens to hundreds of values. Beyond that it does not work.

```
  dismin=np.amin(L)
  dismax=np.amax(L)
  T=stats.uniform(dismin,dismax-dismin).rvs(L.shape[0])
  statistic,critical_values,significance_level=stats.anderson_ksamp([T,L])
  if statistic < critical_values[6]:
     print("L is uniform") 
  else:
     print("L is not uniform")
```

I would like to know if there are other statistical tests in python that have the following properties:

- they check whether a list follows a continuous uniform
  distribution
- they return the p-value
- they're robust even though there are a lot of values. I've noticed that kstest and anderson_ksamp
  don't work well on large datasets.

Comment: Usually tests should work better with a lot of data, not worse...

Comment: Could you tell us specifically (1) exactly what your null hypothesis is (in particular, are you testing against a given uniform distribution or against *some* unspecified uniform distribution) and (2) what you mean by "robust" and "not working"?  This information is important, because the findings you report are contrary to all that is known about these tests.